# How can i access Structure property that is inside Hashtable?

Tags: c#, struct, hashtable

I have the following code that will modify a property inside a structure, and the structure is inside a hash table. Each item in hash table has key of (Int) data type and key of (struct Bag), here is the code i have:

```
struct Bag {

  string apple_type;
  string orange_type;

};

 // Make a new hashtable that will have a key of (int) data type, value of (Bag)
   public static Hashtable bags = new Hashtable();
```

Then i have a method that will read data from a data base reading rows and adding as long there is a row it will add an item (bag(object)) to the hashtable:

```
public void initHashtbl(){


OleDbConnection db_connector = new OleDbConnection(connection_string);

            // Open connection to oracle
            db_connector.Open();

            OleDbCommand sql_commander = new OleDbCommand(sql_statement, db_connector);

            OleDbDataReader data_Reader = sql_commander.ExecuteReader();


            // Read data from sql db server and store it in memory ...


            Bag tempBag = new Bag();

            // row counter used for list view
            int row_counter = 0;

            while (data_Reader.Read()) { // Keep reading data from memory until there is no row

      tempBag.apple_type = data_Reader[0].ToString();

      bags.Add(row_counter, tempBag);
      row_counter++;
}


   for(int bag_item=0;bag_item < bags.Count;bag_item++){

         // Get orange type value from another method that uses another sql statement from another table in db ..
     ((bag) bags[bag_item]).orange_type = getOrangeType(((bag) bags[bag_item]).apple_type);    
}

}
```

How can i access the property of structure that is already inside hash table at later time if i wanted to access it?

Edit:
I'm getting this error:
"Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion."

Comment: are you restricted to using hashtable? there are other structures that can be used Dictionary<int,Bag> eg then you just supply bags[key].orange_type

Comment: Yes i'm getting an error, sorry i forgot to add that to the question post, I have modified it now, you should be able to see it now.

Comment: Dictionary will not allow me to modify that directly, i want to be able to modify that directly for later use, using Dictionary i have to pass a variable to it that will load data to it. Like the following in case i used dictionary with that: bag.TryGetValue(bag_item, out tempBag);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dictionary will not allow me to modify that directly

Neither will a `Hashtable`.  This has nothing to do with `Hashtable` vs `Dictionary`.  The problem is that your "value" in either case is a value type, so you *can't* modify it directly within the collection.  If you *really* need a struct, then you'll have to create a *new* value and put it *back* into the hashtable:

```
bags.Add(1, new Bag() {apple_type="apple1",orange_type="orange1"});

//((Bag)bags[1]).apple_type="apple2";
var bag = (Bag)bags[1];
bag.apple_type = "appple2";
bags[1] = bag;
```

But mutable structs are generally bad, so I would either get the value of the struct right the *first* time (rather than modifying it ourside of the initial load loop) :

```
// row counter used for list view
int row_counter = 0;

while (data_Reader.Read()) { // Keep reading data from memory until there is no row
{
    var appleType = data_Reader[0].ToString();
    Bag tempBag = new Bag() {
        apple_type = appleType,
        orange_type = getOrangeType(appleType)
        };
    bags.Add(row_counter, tempBag);
    row_counter++;
}
```

or use a `class`.

Note that the same code works exactly the same way whether you use a `Hashtable` or a `Dictionary`.

Also, since your "key" is just an incrementing number (and not tied to the value at all), you could just as well use a `List<Bag>` and access the items by index.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me to read an item:

```
        string orangeType = ((Bag) bags[0]).orange_type;
```

To modify an item, I think you must create a new Bag and replace the existing one like this:

```
        bags[0] = newBag;
```

If you try to modify the properties of a bag in the HashTable, then you get the error you reported above.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how value types work, the boxed Bag is a copy of the original, and "unboxing" it by casting back to Bag creates yet another copy. [From the C# language spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> When a value of a value type is converted to type object, an object
>   instance, also called a “box,” is allocated to hold the value, and the
>   value is copied into that box. Conversely, when an object reference is
>   cast to a value type, a check is made that the referenced object is a
>   box of the correct value type, and, if the check succeeds, the value
>   in the box is copied out.

Modifying the copy wouldn't change the original anyway, so it wouldn't make much sense to allow it.

**Corrections:**

To fix your error and to allow modifications to your HashTable of Bag's you should change your value type to reference type:

```
    public class Bag
    {
        public string apple_type { get; set; }
        public string orange_type { get; set; }
    };
```